# BitBake default task

Tags: bitbake

I have been trying out BitBake lately and I am interested in knowing how it works.

I can compile my component like following:

```
bitbake component
```

But I have found that the following line does the same thing (where I specify that BitBake should run the do_build task):

```
bitbake component -c build
```

I.e the component compiles, works and the two are generating the same log files. Is the task do_build is some kind of default value for when I do not specify a task? I have only tried this with this one component, so I am curious if it is generic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bitbake component -c build
```

It is the default behaviour for bitbake as you said. Much more easier for the end user to use it `bitbake component` as mostly you want to build something when you use bitbake.

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to change default task? E.g. if I would want do_compile to be the default task, could I edit that in configuration or class files?

Comment: I'm not an expert bitbake guru, but as far as I know build is not a task ( like do_compile ), build is more of a command. Build means it will go throught the standard workflow ( download, unpack, configure, compile, etc... ).

Comment: you can say e.g: `bitbake myrecipe.bb -b compile` and in this case it will do the compile task and all it's prequisites in dependency graph. You can check task dependencies for a certain .bb file with `bitbake -g myrecipe.bb && less task-depends.dot`. I hope this helps.

Comment: You could change BB_DEFAULT_TASK, but almost nothing else will work at that point as it's assumed that build is the default task.

Answer (score 6):

The default task is set in `meta/classes/base.bbclass`:

```
BB_DEFAULT_TASK ?= "build"
```

Thus you can set `BB_DEFAULT_TASK` to override the default task accordingly, for example in local.conf:

```
BB_DEFAULT_TASK = "compile"
```